# Jquer.Form.Js AJAX file upload issue in IE8 only

Tags: jquery, file-upload, internet-explorer-8, asyncfileupload, jquery-file-upload

I am using Jquery.Form.Js plugin for ajax file upload. It is working fine in all browers and versions except IE8. When i upload in IE 8, the file gets uploaded but browser hangs on response. Suddenly, a popup opens and it says launching application to download and i got he error logs from there as follows. Please let me know the resolution for that. thanks.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.544
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.544 (RTMLDR.030319-5400)
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://localhost:7780/Sistic/internalmessaging/saveFile.htm

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://localhost:7780/Sistic/internalmessaging/saveFile.htm resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [5/14/2013 11:00:11 AM] : Activation of http://localhost:7780/Sistic/internalmessaging/saveFile.htm has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [5/14/2013 11:00:26 AM] System.Net.WebException
        - The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
            at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenAndPush(Uri uri)
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.PushExternalEntityOrSubset(String publicId, String systemId, String baseUriStr, Uri& baseUri, String entityName)
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.DtdParserProxy_PushExternalSubset(String systemId, String publicId)
            at System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseExternalSubset()
            at System.Xml.DtdParser.Parse(Boolean saveInternalSubset)
            at System.Xml.DtdParser.System.Xml.IDtdParser.ParseInternalDtd(IDtdParserAdapter adapter, Boolean saveInternalSubset)
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDtd()
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestValidatingReader.XmlFilteredReader.Read()
            at System.Xml.XmlCharCheckingReader.Read()
            at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Answer (score 0):

This may happen due to incorrect interpretation of response type sent from the server.
Kindly set appropriate response type at the server side and then try.
e.g. `"text/html"`